# Unimodular symmetric integral matrices with diagonal 0 and no $\pm 1$ entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integers, bilinear-form

I am wondering if there exist any square symmetric matrices $A$ with integer entries, all zeros along the diagonal, determinant $1$, and the property that none of the entries in the matrix are equal to $\pm$ 1.  I noticed that they are not any of size 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 0&5&2&4\\ 5&0&3&3
\\ 2&3&0&5\\ 4&3&5&0\end {array}
 \right]$$